# Google Maps API: Search Box and Quotas

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-developers-console

I have a site with a google maps search box and today I started seeing the error "You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API." This is happening whenever a key is pressed in the search box, not just when it's submitted. Also, I'm not getting autocorrect options dropping down.

My dashboard shows only 330 Google Places API requests and 7 Google Maps Javascript API requests being made today. Even that number seems incredibly high. It's for the developer version of my sight so it's just me working on it this afternoon.

How do quotas apply to the search box itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Google

> We now count Google Maps JavaScript API client-side requests towards the daily limit of the associated web service API.*

https://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com.es/2016/06/building-for-scale-updates-to-google.html

If you are facing this error message for Search Box, this should mean that you exceeded a daily quota for Places API web service which is 1000 requests without Billing enabled.

The fact that dashboard shows 330 requests while you are receiving over quota messages is weird. Probably make sense to reach out to Cloud support to figure out if dashboard works correctly.

https://cloud.google.com/support/